# Can I add existing photos in my camera roll to a new photo stream?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photo-stream

I just got a new MacBook Pro with the current version of iPhoto, which supports Photo Stream. I have an iPhone 4, but never had Photo Stream enabled because my previous computer couldn't run the version of iPhoto that was required to use it.

Anyway, I just enabled Photo Stream now, but it seems that it only includes photos that were taken after I enabled it. I have 350+ photos in my camera roll that I'd like to also include in Photo Stream. Is there any way I can import them or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only manually add photos to photostream from iPhoto or Aperture not from the iOS device currently,

So you'd need to sync with iPhoto and manually add to photostream through that.

Comment: I see now - if the non-Photo Stream photos are imported into iPhoto, then I can drag and drop them onto the Photo Stream event. Thanks!

Comment: Hey no problem! I think in iOS 7 you may be able to manually add to your main photostream retrospectively but not in iOS6.  Here's more proof :) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3975936?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Not true, on your iOS device just select as many photos as you want from your Camera Roll, then Share > Photo stream.  This shows up in iPhoto for the Mac and saves a step.

Comment: What are you taking about? There is no option to share to photo stream from iOS.

Comment: Furthermore if you are speaking about creating shared photostreams that's not what he wants to do. He wants to manually add photos to his main photostream. Open your device go to photos, select some items, click the share sheet, you will NOT see photostream as an option. Are you running iOS 7?

Comment: Maybe these grabs will help http://take.ms/DKMuR and http://take.ms/rJiQC

Comment: No they don't help, that photostream button adds images to shared photosteams, not the main between devices photostream. check again.

Comment: That's the whole point, John, that Shared photostreams are shared between all devices, ie iPad, iPhone and Mac.

Comment: Ok, I take your point, however the shared Photostreams from my understanding are a way to transiently share your photos with others. I think the OP was looking to add to the "main" photostream view rather than just a shared stream. Which you can only do in iPhoto or Aperture right?

Comment: Yes as far as I know you can only manually add to the Photostream is iPhoto on the Mac, and even that is tricky.  But agreed, your original suggestion of syncing to iPhoto would involve the least clicks overall when it comes to 300+ photos and is the best way to go for the OP.